# :terminal colorscheme inside Vim is different from either Vim or Host Terminal

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme, iterm2

I have a gruvbox theme applied to Vim inside my `vimrc`.
The problem is that when I run the `:terminal` command inside Vim the colorscheme is different from either the Vim theme or the terminal emulator's theme.

I have tried this on Hyper and iTerm2 with the same results. Somehow neither of the colorschemes are applied to the `:terminal`. I did try looking at the discussions in github, but my knowledge of Vim is not sufficient to understand it.

Can someone explain the problem and the solution? I am running Vim version 8.2.900, Hyper 3.0.2, iTerm 3.3.10.

Comment: The colorscheme may need to set the terminal colors via some special variables. Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: What is that special variable and how? I'm not that proficient in vim scripting just yet. Thank you!

Comment: I believe it’s `g:terminal_ansi_colors`; you can search the plugins code for that and also check the help.

Comment: Oh yes I got it working! I just copy pasted from some of the other themes. Thank you!

Comment: please add an answer if you solved the problem ! Self-answering is accepted and encouraged here, and you’ll be able to accept the answer after a few days. It will help others learn, too!

Comment: ooh ok thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

This was the color schemes defined in paper color theme.
Just pasting this in the vimrc worked!

```
let g:terminal_ansi_colors = [
  \'#eeeeee', '#af0000', '#008700', '#5f8700',
  \'#0087af', '#878787', '#005f87', '#444444',
  \'#bcbcbc', '#d70000', '#d70087', '#8700af',
  \'#d75f00', '#d75f00', '#005faf', '#005f87' ]
```